# remote server error: 500 Response body: {"message":"Internal Server Error"}

Tags: solidity, remix, chainlink

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.7;

import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/ChainlinkClient.sol";

/**
 * Request testnet LINK and ETH here: https://faucets.chain.link/
 * Find information on LINK Token Contracts and get the latest ETH and LINK faucets here: https://docs.chain.link/docs/link-token-contracts/
 */

/**
 * THIS IS AN EXAMPLE CONTRACT WHICH USES HARDCODED VALUES FOR CLARITY.
 * PLEASE DO NOT USE THIS CODE IN PRODUCTION.
 */
contract APIConsumer is ChainlinkClient {
    using Chainlink for Chainlink.Request;
  
    bytes32 public fire;
    
    address private oracle;
    bytes32 private jobId;
    uint256 private fee;
    
    /**
     * Network: Kovan
     * Oracle: 0xc57B33452b4F7BB189bB5AfaE9cc4aBa1f7a4FD8 (Chainlink Devrel   
     * Node)
     * Job ID: d5270d1c311941d0b08bead21fea7747
     * Fee: 0.1 LINK
     */
    constructor() {
        setPublicChainlinkToken();
        oracle = 0x270C24d79A8c334240b3449B8431DaCA1972F438;
        jobId = "c307f6770b6c4ef6b2b168b396f1f9fa";
        fee = 0.1 * 10 ** 18; // (Varies by network and job)
    }
    
    /**
     * Create a Chainlink request to retrieve API response, find the target
     * data, then multiply by 1000000000000000000 (to remove decimal places from data).
     */
    function requestFireData() public returns (bytes32 requestId) 
    {
        Chainlink.Request memory request = buildChainlinkRequest("c307f6770b6c4ef6b2b168b396f1f9fa", address(this), this.fulfill.selector);
        
        // Set the URL to perform the GET request on
        request.add("get", "https://ljiigsoedk.execute-api.ca-central-1.amazonaws.com/default/wildfire");
        
        // Set the path to find the desired data in the API response, where the response format is:
        // {"RAW":
        //   {"ETH":
        //    {"USD":
        //     {
        //      "VOLUME24HOUR": xxx.xxx,
        //     }
        //    }
        //   }
        //  }
        request.add("path", "FIRE_NUMBE");
        
        // Multiply the result by 1000000000000000000 to remove decimals
        //int timesAmount = 10**18;
        //request.addInt("times", timesAmount);
        
        // Sends the request
        return sendChainlinkRequestTo(address(0x270C24d79A8c334240b3449B8431DaCA1972F438), request, 1000000000000000000);
    }
    
    /**
     * Receive the response in the form of uint256
     */ 
    function fulfill(bytes32 _requestId, bytes32 _fire) public recordChainlinkFulfillment(_requestId)
    {
        fire = _fire;
    }

    // function withdrawLink() external {} - Implement a withdraw function to avoid locking your LINK in the contract
}
```

trying to make http call but getting error. it is calling my node to run the job though.

```
{
  "name": "",
  "initiators": [
    {
      "id": 3,
      "jobSpecId": "c307f677-0b6c-4ef6-b2b1-68b396f1f9fa",
      "type": "runlog",
      "params": {
        "address": "0x270c24d79a8c334240b3449b8431daca1972f438"
      }
    }
  ],
  "tasks": [
    {
      "jobSpecId": "c307f6770b6c4ef6b2b168b396f1f9fa",
      "type": "httpget"
    },
    {
      "jobSpecId": "c307f6770b6c4ef6b2b168b396f1f9fa",
      "type": "jsonparse"
    },
    {
      "jobSpecId": "c307f6770b6c4ef6b2b168b396f1f9fa",
      "type": "ethbytes32"
    },
    {
      "jobSpecId": "c307f6770b6c4ef6b2b168b396f1f9fa",
      "type": "ethtx"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Can you include the code where you are making the call?

Comment: the contract is deployed in remix and requestFireData function makes the call.

Comment: Did you end up solving this? I can't tell from your answer.

Comment: not yet, the only plausible reason for it to go 500 (internal server error) at this point of the investigation is that it does not get its parameters.

Comment: it works from postman if given parameters in the correct format, so by deduction that if it does not return anything, it's because it wasn't when called from solidity. 
you'll also get 500 if you just remove parameters from postman.... so its the way from the contract to the job theres something wrong

Answer (score 0):

changed it to request.add("farm", "-123.95908355712889, 53.25042550620077");
FIRE_NUMBE is a list of fires, so it fails trying to make the request
added a bridge with the api url, which is now used in a new job, so that everything sent using req.add ends up in the body of the request

now need to make requestFireData() accept a set of coordinates, that would then be included in the request

**fixed **had to edit the lambda to accept string, not array, and the 0.10.15 node expecting another format than we send to it from the adapter. needed to format the output from the api

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).